# how to fetch data from two table with same where condition in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

i have two tables in my database 
1)order_construction_employees
2)order_dismantling_employees

both have the same structure like

--id

--order_id

--employee_id

I want to fetch the record from these two tables with where condition of `employee_id`

Example: fetch the record from two tables where `employee_id = session('employee_id')`

Answer (score 0):

your sql query would be as following:

```
SELECT OCE.id as OCE_id,OCE.order_id as OCE_order, OCE.employee_id as OCE_eid,
       ODE.id as ODE_id,ODE.order_id as ODE_order, ODE.employee_id as ODE_eid 
FROM order_construction_employees AS OCE 
LEFT JOIN order_dismantling_employees AS ODE 
     ON OCE_eid = ODE_eid
WHERE OCE_eid = session('employee_id')
```

Comment: i need it in laravel

Comment: your Query is wrong by the way.
thanks for your try bro.

Answer (score 0):

```
$constructionEmployees = DB::table('order_construction_employees')
    ->select('order_construction_employees.id', 'order_construction_employees.order_id', 'order_construction_employees.employee_id');

$employees = DB::table("order_dismantling_employees")
    ->select('order_dismantling_employees.id', 'order_dismantling_employees.order_id', 'order_dismantling_employees.employee_id')
    ->union($constructionEmployees)
    ->where('employee_id', session('employee_id'));
    ->get();
```

Hope if this can help you

Comment: if need all data without remove duplicate, can change union into unionAll